# How can I get GHC to emit a warning for a given function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Suppose I've decided that everywhere in a given code base (package) I want to use a custom `getCurrentTimeMicroseconds` rather than `getCurrentTime`. Is there a way for me to get GHC to emit warnings me about uses of `getCurrentTime`, only in that code base? (Not for anything upstream or downstream.)

Bonus question, suppose I want to selectively allow usages with an explicit annotation at the use site (preferably not module-wide). Is this also possible?

Comment: Does `getCurrentTimeMicroseconds` emit a different type than `getCurrentTime`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it does not, at present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what types are for. The type you use for times should reflect the constraints you want to place on the values it represents.

For example, you could wrap `UTCTime` like so:

```
newtype UTCTimeMicroseconds = UTCTimeMicroseconds { picos :: UTCTime }

microsecondsFromPicos :: UTCTime -> UTCTimeMicroseconds
microsecondsFromPicos = ...

getCurrentTimeMilliseconds :: IO UTCTimeMicroseconds
getCurrentTimeMilliseconds = microsecondsFromPicos <$> getCurrentTime
```

And use the new type everywhere in your package that you need times to have this property.

If you want to be strict about it, don't export the `UTCTimeMicroseconds` constructor, so the only way to get one of these values is to use `microsecondsFromPicos`, which enforces your requirement.

That makes any misuse an error, not a warning, but in most cases that's what you want anyway.

When you do want to use `UTCTime` with the full resolution, or just don't care, you can just use that type as usual. It'll be easy to find the places in your code base where that happens, because they'll be the *only* places where `UTCTime` is used.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this right now, but I think the closest you can get is something like:

- create a new package `my-time` that depends on `time`
- re-export your shim functions annotated with warnings, like

  ```
  import qualified Data.Time as Time
  {-# WARNING getCurrentTime "you should prefer getCurrentTimeMicroseconds" #-}
  getCurrentTime = Time.getCurrentTime
  ```
- depend on `my-time` in your packages

obviously this doesn't give you a way to enforce *not* importing `Data.Time.getCurrentTime`, and is even less satisfying when the code you want to shim is in Prelude or `base`.

Comment: It might be nice if e.g. `stack` could allow local packages with conflicting names to shadow the published hackage version for multi-package projects